# efficiently flattening a large multiidex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large DataFrame that looks like this:

```
                  A B 
SPH2008 3/21/2008 1 2
        3/21/2008 1 2 
        3/21/2008 1 2
SPM2008 6/21/2008 1 2 
        6/21/2008 1 2
        6/21/2008 1 2
```

And I have the following code which is intended to flatten and acquire the unique pairs of the two indeces into a new DF:

```
indeces = [df.index.get_level_values(0), df.index.get_level_values(1)]
tmp = pd.DataFrame(data=indeces).T.drop_duplicates()
tmp.columns = ['ID', 'ExpirationDate']
tmp.sort_values('ExpirationDate', inplace=True)
```

However, this operation takes a remarkably long amount of time. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `pandas.DataFrame.index.drop_duplicates`

```
pd.DataFrame([*df.index.drop_duplicates()], columns=['ID', 'ExpirationDate'])

        ID ExpirationDate
0  SPH2008      3/21/2008
1  SPM2008      6/21/2008
```

---

With older versions of Python that can't unpack in that way

```
pd.DataFrame(df.index.drop_duplicates().tolist(), columns=['ID', 'ExpirationDate'])
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, You can also `groupby` the levels of your multiindex, then create a dataframe from that with your desired columns:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).groups.keys(), columns=['ID', 'ExpirationDate'])
        ID ExpirationDate
0  SPH2008      3/21/2008
1  SPM2008      6/21/2008
```